# Can't get the gnome run dialog running with unity on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity

I'd like to use the gnome version of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to run commands since Unity's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't support tab completion.

So far I've tried the following steps:

1. Open CompizConfig Settings Manager
2. Go to General->Gnome Compatibility
3. Assign Run Dialog to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (which warns me I'm disabling 'Key to execute a command' which is under Desktop->UbuntuUnity Plugin->Key to execute a command)
4. Restart computer

After logging back in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't do anything.

I've also gone to System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->System->Show the run command prompt and set it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> with no luck.

Any idea why the gnome run dialog isn't popping up? I've read other similar questions on this site which seemed to indicate the above steps have solved this problem in the past, but for some reason they aren't doing the trick for me. Is this some kind of bug with my setup? Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the gnome run-dialog is now provided by the " gnome-panel-control" package, the evoke command would be

```
gnome-panel-control --run-dialog
```

Thing is it can't run unless gnome-panel is running which it typically  isn't in a unity* session.

To see open a terminal while in a unity session, start gnome-panel, then try your binding or open another terminal, run the above command. (assumes the package & gnome-panel are installed

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ran gnome-panel and was able to run gnome-panel-control --run-dialog like you suggested but it doesn't run otherwise. Hopefully unity's command executor gets tab completion at some point. In the mean time I'll stick with mapping alt+f2 to gmrun or some such utility.

Comment: If I find a bug report on will edit in, thought I had seen one. Because I do new installs frequently I pre-populate the run history in gsettings from a saved text file, though not the question here